# What means mean and stddev in keras/tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

in below part of code what means mean and stddev ?
I know the seed is put to 1 so if you generate random values those are always the same. But don't know about mean and stddev?

I know the seed is put on 1 so you should have always the same values generated

```
    with tf.Session() as test:
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    y_true = (None, None, None)
    y_pred = (tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1),
              tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=1, stddev=1, seed = 1),
              tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=3, stddev=4, seed = 1))
    loss = triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred)

    print("loss = " + str(loss.eval()))
```

Comment: they are the parameters of the normal distribution from which you are sampling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mean](https://www.mathsisfun.com/definitions/mean.html) is the average of the numbers which will be generated by tf.random_normal(). Similarly, stddev stands for [Standard deviation](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html) of the data.

- if mean=1.2 and stddev=3.4 then, the number matrix generated by tf.random_normal() will have mean and standard deviation as 1.2 and 3.4 respectively.

Comment: I'm I right if I say that the command y_pred = (tf.random_normal([3, 128], mean=6, stddev=0.1, seed = 1) will produce a set of numbers where the mean is 6 and stddev = 0.1 ?